# Wget in a specific directory times out, but does not when executed in another directory

Tags: linux, operating-system, wget, redhat

On a RHEL 7 VM, wgets within a specific directory timesout but when I execute the same exact wget command from inside another directory, it works well.

Wget works from /var/tmp

> -bash-4.2$ cd /var/tmp/
>
> -bash-4.2$ wget http:///automation/mongodb-releases/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz
>
> --2018-10-10 22:48:30--  http://opsmgr.phx.aexp.com/automation/mongodb-releases/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz
>
> Resolving opsmgr.phx.aexp.com (opsmgr.phx.aexp.com)... 148.173.148.36
>
> Connecting to opsmgr.phx.aexp.com
>
> (opsmgr.phx.aexp.com)|148.173.148.36|:80... connected. HTTP request
>
> sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified
>
> [application/octet-stream] Saving to:
>
> ‘mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz.1’
>
> ```
> [                                                                                              <=>
> ```
>
> ] 113,450,895 2.34MB/s   in 52s
>
> 2018-10-10 22:49:22 (2.07 MB/s) -
>   ‘mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz.1’ saved [113450895]

But when I cd to another directory, and execute the same exact wget from there, it times out

> -bash-4.2$ cd - /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation
>
> -bash-4.2$ rm -f mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz
>
> -bash-4.2$ wget http://opsmgr.phx.aexp.com/automation/mongodb-releases/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz
>
> --2018-10-10 22:49:41--  http://opsmgr.phx.aexp.com/automation/mongodb-releases/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz
>
> Resolving opsmgr.phx.aexp.com (opsmgr.phx.aexp.com)... 148.173.148.36
>
> Connecting to opsmgr.phx.aexp.com
>
> (opsmgr.phx.aexp.com)|148.173.148.36|:80... connected. HTTP request
>
> sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified
>
> [application/octet-stream] Saving to:
>
> ‘mongodb-linux-x86_64-enterprise-rhel70-3.6.7.tgz’
>
> ```
> [                                                                                                                         <=>                                                  ] 12,313,416
> ```
>
> --.-K/s              ^C
>   -bash-4.2$

Any ideas as to why this would happen? This is super weird.

Comment: Off-topic. Professional system and network administrators, ask on Server Fault.

Comment: Maybe `/var/tmp` and `/var/lib` are on different filesystems?